# Javafx - how to change the behavior of upTableColumn

Tags: java, javafx

I have a TableView with 2 columns (TableColumn).

I delegated one of the columns (TableColumn) to "on edit commit" (via scene builder).

When I write a new value to one of the cells column and press ENTER I'm getting into the delegated function.

But, if I'm writing a value and click with the mouse on other cell, the value is not saved (and the delegated function is not being called)  (because I didn't press ENTER).

Is there a way to change this behavior ?
Is there a way to do it via scene builder or from the code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default TextField behavior requires that user presses the Enter key to commit the edit. This can be changed by extending [TableCell](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableCell.html) class to commit editing on focus change, like in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#JFXUC376) TableView tutorial. Precisely, look at the implementation of the EditingCell class and its usage in this example.

Basically, all that is needed is that text field for the table cell set focus change listener which will call commitEdit(), like in the following example:

```
textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
  @Override
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, 
                      Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) {
    if (!arg2) {
      commitEdit(value);
    }
  }
});
```

Above mentioned example shows how to set new table cell type for the table column in Java code but it can be set in the FXML too.

Comment: Thanks, but in your example you add listner to textField. my TableView (or TableColumn) does not contains any textField...
so what am I missing here ?

Comment: textField is member of the newly implemented table cell class. When cell is put into the edit state, it shows this text field to enable data input. My example is just short excerpt from the referred detailed example. That example lack few minor things, like calling requestFocus() when text field is shown, but it is good starting point to understand how to implement editable table cell. Please, look at the example pointed by the link for details. Does this help you a little?

Comment: soory, it doesnt help. I'mm not using textBox in order to insert input into the table.  The user insert the input directly to the table. I read the link you give me, and they use textbox in order to insert input, and the table is used for the output.

Comment: I am afraid you didn't understand me. That text field is not outside of the table. When user, for example, double click the cell he wants to edit, table goes in the edit mode and text field shows at the place of that cell. Then when user change focus outside of the text field, contents of the cell is rendered back with Label. Original TextFieldTableCell works like that too, but it doesn't commit changes on focus change event, and the example I've referred to fix that. The link shows first table input example with external text field, and then also with input in the table itself.